# SonarQube gitlab-plugin shows inline comment only in Master branch

Tags: sonarqube, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using [sonar-gitlab-plugin](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin)@4.0.0 and sonarQube@7.5,

My gitlab-ci.yml is:

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=$SONAR_KEY \
  -Dsonar.sources=. \
  -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL \
  -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN
  -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA \
  -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME \
  -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_ID
```

---

### Commit in non-master branch

If this commit not on the `Master` branch, when quality gate is failed, SonarQube always generates global comment like below: 
[image: commit in non-master branch]

```
But always says "reported no issues" and `no inline comment`,
```

---

### Commit in Master branch

However, commit in `Master` branch (with same changes), it generates global comment with issues and inline comments :

[image: commit in Master branch]

---

I expect it generates global comment with issues and inline comment on all branch.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Branch Analysis and Pull Request Analysis are available from Developer Edition as mentions at https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/ and https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/

Comment: Hi, @CharleeChitsuk, the branch you mention is sonarqube branch, does this relate to gitlab branch?

Comment: It is a git branch as well. Please visit the following for FAQ, https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/branches-faq/

Comment: Hi @IanZhong, would you mind sharing your entire `gitlab-ci.yml` file. I'm stuck there.

Comment: have you been able to resolve it? as I'm having exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line also.

```
-Dsonar.gitlab.unique_issue_per_inline=true
```

it should look like.

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_ID -Dsonar.gitlab.unique_issue_per_inline=true
```